# Using mod_rewrite to add a directory

Tags: mod-rewrite

I have a client which requires their site to be on:

**www.clienturl.com/asubdirectory**

The site that will be stored in the sub directory won't be able to have the links updated to:

**www.clienturl.com/asubdirectory/a_file.php**

They'll just be:

**www.clienturl.com/a_file.php**

But clicking these links would redirect or rewrite the user to:

**www.clienturl.com/asubdirectory/a_file.php**

Is there anything I can do with mod_rewrite and/or aliases or anythng else?

Thanks in advance guys!

Mike Pearce

Edit:

This is my current set of rewrite rules:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
       RewriteEngine On
       RewriteBase /
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
       RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule !^asubdirectory($|/) asubdirectory%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've modified my question above in response to your reply.

Thanks,

Mike